# Dummy email address and Email parser

Tags: java, android, c++, email, parsing

If you're not interested in helping a beginner in email parsing, don't read further.

I have been programming for a while so I know the gist of things. But, I'm really interested in creating a dummy email address and then set up a parsing program inside of it (if thats even how you do it)

Scenario:

I have an email account which receives certain emails which need parsing. I want to be able to forward those emails to a "dummy" email address which is basically just a program which parses the email for sender, subject, and message. I would prefer to write a runnable jar program or something on windows but I'm willing to do web programming if need be. Android programming is also an option for me.

What would I do to get started? I'm not asking for anyone to write out everything, I just need a starting point for all of this.

Thanks!

Comment: I would go with a lib that connects to your mail server and retrieves the mails vie either POP3 or SMTP protocols. (Search Google and you will find plenty.) Otherwise you may end up coding your own lib to connect to your mail via those protocols or coding your own web server which is mother of overkills for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I didn't know the terms for all of this but I found something like this: [link] (http://alvinalexander.com/java/javamail-pop-pop3-reader-email-inbox-example) which is what I needed to start. I realized I might need to save the info but for the most part, parsing it and not saving might be what I need. life saver!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe can be solved like this:

1/ Create a catch-all address *@yourdomain.com which will receive all incoming e-mails except those who match an existing email address (e.g. contact@yourdomain.col)

2/ Pipe all incoming e-mails to a script with Procmail

```
:0
| `/home/foouser/scripts/footool/footool.sh`
```

3/ Let the script process the e-mail (read headers, save in db, ...)

Another, probably much more easy solution would be to use a web service like [cloudmailin.com](http://cloudmailin.com) for this. If the structure of the e-mail is always the same, an email parsing solution like [mailparser.io](https://mailparser.io) could help you as well.